# Erro na Abertura de banco de dados System.InvalidOperationException?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-mobile

Estou usando o webMatrix, para desenvolver um exemplo em JqueryMobile, estou tendo o seguinte erro

```html
@{
    Layout="~/shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Home";
    Page.Header = "Categorias";
    var db  = Database.Open("Northwind40.sdf");
    var sql = @"SELECT [CATEGORY ID] AS ID, [CATEGORY NAME] AS NAME FROM CATEGORIES 
    ORDER BY [CATEGORY NAME]";
    var data = db.Query(sql);
}


<div data-role="content">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">

          @foreach(var item in data){
            <li><a href="/Category/@item.ID">@item.NAME</a></li>
          }

    </ul>

</div>
```

Mensagem de Erro:

```html
  Connection string "Northwind40.sdf" was not found.
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

    Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Connection string "Northwind40.sdf" was not found.

    Source Error: 

    Line 3:      Page.Title = "Home";
    Line 4:      Page.Header = "Categorias";
    Line 5:      var db  = Database.Open("Northwind40.sdf");
    Line 6:      var sql = @"SELECT [CATEGORY ID] AS ID, [CATEGORY NAME] AS NAME FROM CATEGORIES 
    Line 7:      ORDER BY [CATEGORY NAME]";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua:

```
var db  = Database.Open("Northwind40.sdf");
```

Por:

```
var db  = Database.Open("UmaConnectionStringVálida");
```

Não sei que tecnologia de banco de dados esse objeto `Database` usa, mas possivelmente este arquivo `.sdf` nem existe no seu exemplo.

Comment: Agradeço, o erro foi corrigido assim : var db = database.user ("Northwind40");